# ruby openstack swift client that works with v3 identify version

Tags: ruby, openstack, openstack-swift

I have nearly tried every gem listed on https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/SDKs to make a client work with openstack, but so far none of them is working.

Is there any ruby swift client that can work with openstack? my openstack has the following environment variables

```
export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME=default
export OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME=default
export OS_PROJECT_NAME=somename
export OS_USERNAME=somename
export OS_PASSWORD=somelongpassword
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://someurl:5000/v3
export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
export OS_IMAGE_API_VERSION=2
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like none of the ruby sdks work as of now with keystone v3.

i figured out that i need to do three requests only:
1) login
2) upload contents
3) download data

so i decided to use curl and plain old ruby for now to work with openstack.